# Error for db select with phpunit and Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit

I would like to use unit tests in a ZF project, so I created the test class but here is the error :

> Fatal error: Call to a member function select() on a non-object in ...\CardMapper.php

The concerned lines are :

```
$this->db = Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::getDefaultAdapter();

$select = $this->db->select()->from(array('c' => 'cards'));
```

And there is no problem when I use a browser.

Here is my phpunit.xml (from an other zf project without database) :

```
<phpunit bootstrap="./bootstrap.php">
    <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
        <directory>./application</directory>
    </testsuite>
    <testsuite name="Library Test Suite">
        <directory>./library</directory>
    </testsuite>

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory suffix=".php">../../library/Zend</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

the bootstrap.php :

```
<?php

// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'testing'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));

require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
```

And the test class :

```
<?php

class CardControllerTest extends Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase
{

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->bootstrap = new Zend_Application(APPLICATION_ENV, APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini');
        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function testList()
    {
        $this->dispatch('/card');
    }
}
```

I tried a lot of things but nothing really worked. Some code changed the error for a "no default module found".

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the problem :

in the application.ini, I only put the database config for the development environment while unit tests were still using the testing environment configuration.

So problem solved !